# Methods to detect which social networks users visit?

Tags: javascript, tracking

Are there recommended ways to determine which social networks my users are part of? I have the know-how to build a system that does this but I wanted to get other people's opinions and recommendations on how they might do it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This JavaScript tool does just what you need: http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/socialhistoryjs/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yeah, this is basically the same "know-how". I implemented something similar in a Twitter promo tool I wrote in February called Fathomer (http://code.google.com/p/fathomer/). I have a new version in testing that adds reporting in Google Analytics.